# Eigenvalues of [symmetric] matrix A whose product $AA$ is diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I'm sorry if my terminology is incorrect, please step in if you have to.

Shortly,
I have a symmetric matrix (don't know if symmetry is relevant here):

$$A =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        2 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\implies AA =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        4 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 4 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

and we can easily say $\sigma(AA) = \{ 4 \}$
with the proper algebraic multiplicity of 4 (i.e 3).

Now, we know that the spectrum of $A$ follows the property
$
\sigma(AA) = \sigma(A)^2
$

How can I properly infer the eigenvalues of $A$ from this property? (It should be $\sigma(A) = \{2, -2\}$ where algebraic multiplicity of 2 is 2.)

Is there any other faster way?

I wish I had been more formal,
looking forward for your replies,

Thanks.

Comment: You can't determine the eigenvalues of $A$ from $AA$ because $x \mapsto x^2$ is not injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, so it has real eigenvalues. But the only eigenvalue of $A^2$ is $4$, and the eigenvalues of of $A^2$ are the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$. Hence the only possible eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm 2$.

On the other hand, the multiplicities aren't uniquely determined: Flipping the sign of the middle entry of $A$ changes the sign of one of the 2-eigenvalues but leaves $AA$ unchanged. Similarly, one could take $A=\pm 2I_3$ for which the only one of the two eigenvalues appears (with multiplicity 3) without changing $A^2$. So the multiplicities aren't uniquely determined by $A^2$.